# How to mark the peak with Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I use the `plot` function to mark the peak?

Example:

```
a = [0 1 3 23 3 9 10 28 2]
[p,locs] = findpeaks(a)
```

Result：

```
p =

23 28


locs =

4 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont provide an x range so create one (you can change this to what you want).

```
 figure
 x = [1:length(a)];
 plot(x,a,'k');
```

The above plots your original data points the following will

```
 hold on
 plot(locs,p,'ro');
```

plot your peaks as red circle points on top of the original series. If you need a non-integer x-range you will need to calculate the appropriate values that correspond to the indices in your `locs` array and use those x values instead.